# O value do TextInput não muda - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, data, input, asyncstorage

Então eu to pegando esses valores no AsyncStorage e eles vem do meu banco de dados, até ai tudo bem, eu pego as const's e jogo nelas oa valores que eu puxei.
porém eu preciso conseguir editar isso pelas entradas de texto, e eu n consigo mudar o value das mesmas.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; 
import { View, Text, TextInput, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native'; 
import {css} from '../../style/Css'
import MenuAreaRestrita from '../../assets/components/MenuAreaRestrita';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


export default function Editar({navigation}){ 




const[paciente_nome, setPaciente_nome] = useState()
const[paciente_cpf, setPaciente_Cpf] = useState(null)

useEffect(()=> {
    async function getNo_completo(){
        let response = await AsyncStorage.getItem('pacienteData'); 
        let json = JSON.parse(response); 
        setPaciente_nome((json.no_completo).toString()) 
        setPaciente_Cpf(json.nu_cpf)
         
        
    } 

    getNo_completo(); 
    

}) 

return( 
    <View style={css.containerMenu}>  
    <MenuAreaRestrita title='Editar' navigation={navigation}/>
    <Text style={css.textCadastro}> Insira os dados do paciente:</Text>
    <TextInput style ={css.textInputCadastro}
                placeholder  ='Nome:'
                editable={true} 
                value={(paciente_nome).toString()}
                onChangeText ={text=>String(setPaciente_nome(text))}
            />
     <TextInput style ={css.textInputCadastro}
                placeholder  ='CPF:'
                editable
                value={formataCPF(String(paciente_cpf))}
                onChangeText ={text=>setPaciente_Cpf(text)}
            />
     
   
            
    </View>
)
```

}

Comment: O que retorna nessa linha? let json = JSON.parse(response);

Comment: os dados do paciente. Mas de toda forma o erro tava no useEffect, eu vacilei e acabou que essa função tava sendo chamada o tempo todo, por isso eu n conseguia atualizar

Comment: é mesmo faltou colocar o array [] lá nas dependencias dele. colocar uma resposta ai pode ajudar outros usuarios.

Comment: Verdade, vou fazer isso. Vlw

Answer (score -1):

Então galera o que acontece é que a minha função estava sendo chamada diversas vezes por tanto, sempre trazia o valor antigo.

A solução foi a seguinte:

```
useEffect(()=> {
async function getNo_completo(){
    let response = await AsyncStorage.getItem('pacienteData'); 
    let json = JSON.parse(response); 
    setPaciente_nome((json.no_completo).toString()) 
    setPaciente_Cpf(json.nu_cpf)
     
    
} 

getNo_completo(); 


}, [])
```

Ou seja por um array vazio no fim da função, dessa forma ela é chamada apenas uma vez.